# Msysgit GPG error

Tags: git

I'm getting the following error on Windows with msysgit. Doesn't matter whether or not I am doing it from the command prompt or the BASH bundled with Git:

> gpg: error loading `iconv.dll': The specified module could not be found.

Google hasn't yielded any good results yet. Any idea of how to get around this? I see libiconv2.dll in the same bin folder as gpg.exe.

Comment: I googled "iconv.dll" and this was the second result: http://www.gnupg.org/download/iconv.en.html

Comment: @Chris, you should refactor your comment as the answer to this question. It helped me, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

First, you should download the dll file "iconv.dll". The DLL is available as a ZIP file at the address ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/binary/libiconv-1.9.1.dll.zip. You should also get the corresponding ".sig" file and verify the integrity . This DLL has been built from the source package libiconv-1.9.1.tar.gz available at the same FTP sites. We distribute it separately for convenience and because GnuPG only requires this DLL and not the other files from the binary package. For copying conditions see the included file "COPYING.LIB".

To install this DLL, unzip it and copy the file "iconv.dll" to a directory where you usually keep DLLs. If you don't know such a directory, it is safe to copy it into the same directory as the "gpg.exe" file is stored.

Answer (score 1):

If the 'bash bundled with git' means you're using cygwin:

Make sure you've got the cygwin gpg installed and it's what shows up with `which gpg`.

You can install gpg using the cygwin installer (setup.exe/setup-x86.exe/setup-x86_64.exe). Search for 'gnupg'. It'll be under Utils.